# How to replace underscores in filename with spaces while copying to a directory in unix

Tags: linux, unix

I want to copy a file (containing underscores in its name) to a directory where I want to replace underscores with spaces in the filename.

```
 cp -pr myDir/myFile_With_Underscore.pdf my2Dir
```

I want to put filename with replacing underscore with spaces in my2Dir.

Like **myFile_With_Underscore.pdf** should be **myFile With Underscore.pdf** in my2Dir.

Comment: Just consider that intentionally placing spaces in a filename can cause a great number of problems with poorly written scripts and make the files more difficult to administer from the command-line. Generally people look to replace spaces with underscores for just that reason, rare to go in reverse...

Answer (score 1):

you could use the `tr` command (see: [`man tr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) ):

```
cp "/path/to/${source}" "/new/path/to/$(echo ${source} | tr '_' ' ')"
```

`tr` will translate one set of chars to another, thus replacing every `_` with a space.

One very important note: Do not forget to quote the copy parameters when containing spaces. Without quotes every word would be considered a seperate character. So:

```
cp my_file my new file # NOT OK
cp my_file "my_new_file" # OK, as the parameter with spaces is quoted
cp "my_file" "my new file" # Also OK. Quotes on the first not neccessary, but dont hurt either
```

As `tr` will do, you could also do this with several other commands such as [`sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) or [`awk`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk). For example using `sed`:

```
cp "/path/to/${source}" "/new/path/to/$(echo ${source} | sed 's/\_/ /g')"
```

But I would recommand sticking to `tr` with such easy tasks.

Comment: `$()` is launching a command in a subshell and returning you the output, so it executes `echo ${source} | tr '_' ' '`. `${source}` is a variable. of course you have to replace this with your code...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rename` for this, to change all PDF files in the current directory, do

`rename 'y/_/ /' *.pdf`

---

In your concrete example do:

`cp -p myDir/myFile_With_Underscore.pdf my2Dir && rename 'y/_/ /' my2Dir/myFile_With_Underscore.pdf`

Comment: I see, my Ubuntu machine had it installed by default, you can probably install it from your distro's repositories. What are you using?

Comment: I'm running the command through Tectia terminal (linux). Its not taking rename command after cp in the same line

Comment: Well, I mean what Linux Distribution is it you try to run `rename` on?

Comment: **note:** the `rename` provided by most distributions from the `util-linux` package does not support `y/foo/bar/`

Comment: It is SSH terminal. I'm not sure which version it is using

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
for i in myDir/myFile_With_Underscore.pdf; do \
cp $i myDir2/${$(basename $i)//_/ }; done
```

If you were in the same directory where the origin file is located you could omit the `basename`, for example:

```
for i in .myFile_With_Underscore.pdf; do cp $i ../myDir2/${i//_/ }; done
```

Notice the `${i//_/ }`, in order to manipulate the name of the file, the name needs to be in the variable `$i` therefore the use of the `for i in`

[${string//substring/replacement}](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html#SUBSTRREPL01) Replace all matches of **$substring** with **$replacement**.